# Calculating Distances Between Polygons: One to Many, ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

### My Problem:

I have a set of sites (green), a 5 km buffer around them (purple) and a set of special areas (blue).

[image]

I need to calculate the distances between each site and each special area intersecting with the sites buffer.

However, a special area is not unique to a single buffer and where a special area crosses more than one buffer (i.e. central blue site), I need a separate row, with the distance between each site and that special area.

### Desired output:

A layer where the attribute table as a row for each distance between the site and the special area within the buffer, with the area of each special area included (calculated before this analysis).

What would be the work flow to get to this desired result? 'Near' won't help as it will just tell me the distance to the nearest special area. I'm not sure a 'near table' would help where a special area is in the buffer of more than one buffer.

Comment: Have you tried Near tool (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) with a search radius of 5 km?

Comment: I think I may have actually solved it with a near table. Did not realise you could enter a search radius, so thank you for that!

Comment: Nice! You can post that as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using a 'near table'- using a 5 km search radius and unchecking the box saying to only use the nearest feature.